# How to get the average row number per rank in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, average, rank, row-number

Is there any option to get the average of the same values using the `RANK()` function in PostgreSQL? Here is the example of what I want to do:

[image: example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will do the trick for you

```
SELECT
  test_score,
  row_number() OVER (ORDER BY test_score) AS rank,
  rank() OVER (ORDER BY test_score) 
    + (count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY test_score) - 1) / 2.0 AS "rank (with tied)"
FROM scores
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/7731)

#### Remarks:

- What you believe is the "rank" is really the `row_number()` (i.e. a consecutive series of positive integer with no gaps and no duplicates).
- That rank "with tied" that you're looking for can be calculated from the real `rank()` (rank with gaps) + the number of *other* elements of the same rank divided by two. This is a faster shortcut to calculate the average `row_number()` given your specific requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you want `row_number()`, not `rank()`. Rank will not give repeated values in the way you presented. To get the answer you're looking for:

```
with rwn as (
  select
    test_score
    ,row_number() over (order by test_score) rwn
  from
    score
)
select
  test_score
  ,avg(rwn) average_rank
from
  rwn
group by
  test_score;
```

Here's a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/28a4f/3).

Answer (score 0):

[@Lukas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36823637/939860) and [@jeremy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36823542/939860) already explained the difference between `rank()` and `row_number()` you seemed to be missing.

You can also compute the row number (`rn`), and the average over `rn` (`avg_rn`) per rank (= per group of same values) in the next step:

```
SELECT test_score, rn, avg(rn) OVER (PARTITION BY test_score) AS avg_rn
FROM  (SELECT test_score, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY test_score) AS rn FROM tbl) sub;
```

You need a subquery because window functions cannot be nested on the same query level.

You need another *window function* (*not* an *aggregate function* like has been suggested) to preserve all original rows.

The result is ordered by `rn` by default (for this simple query), but this is just an implementation detail. To guarantee an ordered result, add an explicit `ORDER BY` (for practically no cost):

```
...
ORDER  BY rn;
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e0b05/4)